# Browser contradiction: How come sessionStorage is cleared once the tab is closed, but still can be restored from history?

Tags: http, browser, local-storage, session-storage

From the official Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage,  it states:

> A page session lasts as long as the tab or the browser is open, and
> survives over page reloads and restores.
>
> Opening a page in a new tab
> or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level
> browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
>
> Opening
> multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage for
> each tab/window.
>
> Duplicating a tab copies the tab's sessionStorage
> into the new tab.
>
> Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears
> objects in sessionStorage.

Isn't there an obvious contradiction?

`Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.`

in the meantime,

`A page session lasts as long as the tab or the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.`

I have tested with my website, which stores access tokens in sessionStorage. After I close the tab, I can restore the page from history and I do not need to sign in again.

But how can this be right?
When I close the tab, the session is ended and objects in sessionStorage are cleared.

But when I restore from history, the sessionStorage is back again???

Questions:

1. Isn't this an obvious contradiction? How can this be right??
2. How does it delete the sessionStorage object when closing the tab? Is it a complete deletion or still saved somewhere? which leads to the next question:
3. When the page is restored and sessionStorage is restored, where is the data restored from?
4. Is there a time limit over which one can no longer restore a closed page/tab?